# Multiple text box values from {VIEW} on select of select box to be displayed in controller in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To retrieve value from a text box in a form (view) to controller in codeigniter php on selection of selectbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825796/to-retrieve-value-from-a-text-box-in-a-form-view-to-controller-in-codeigniter-p)

view code

```
  <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows">
<label>
 <select name="select<?=$i;?>"><option value="">NO</option><option  value="<?=$row ->product_name;?>,<?=$row->barcode?>">YES</option>
```

textbox code

```
      <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><input type="text" name ="Quantity"/></td>
```

Controller code

```
function cartoutput() {
    $category = $this->input->post('Category');
    $num = $this->input->post('numOflimit');
    $productName = $this->input->post('product_name');
    $barcode = $this->input->post('barcode');
    $quantity = $this->input->post('Quantity$i');
    //$values = $this->input->post('$i');
    echo $quantity;
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $num; $x++) {
        $userArray = $_POST["select" . $x . ""];
    }
          $userArray = split(',', $userArray);
            $productName = $userArray[0];
            $barcode = $userArray[1];
            $quantity = $userArray[2];

            $flag = $this->cartmodel->productCategory($category);

        }
    }
```

how to fetch the respective textbox value according to selected selectbox and provide it in controller

Answer (score 0):

You are never recalling the POSTed value of `quantity`.

What happens if you do:

```
$quant = $this->input->post('quantity');
var_dump($quant);
```

Comment: <input type="text" name ="Quantity<?=$i;?>"/>  something like this???

Comment: Er, no. You named the SELECT list 'select$i' (I missed the prepended select in my original answer), so when you POST this to a controller, inside that controller function, do $x = $this->input->post('select$i') for whatever value of $i you set.

Comment: but i get the output as **array**

Comment: Have you considered print_r()'ing the array?

Comment: wait i will post my controller code